# 'List of lists' to 'list' without losing empty lists from the original list of lists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Usually I would use a comprehension to change my list of lists to a list. However, I don't want to lose the empty lists as I will zip the final list to another list and I need to maintain the placings.

I have something like

`list_of_lists = [['a'],['b'],[],['c'],[],[],['d']]` and I use this

`[x for sublist in list_of_lists for x in sublist]`
which gives me

`['a','b','c','d']`
but what I would like is

`['a','b','','c','','','d']`

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I am new to python.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It's not a stupid question :p

Comment: Are you sure it is `[[a],[b],[],[c],[],[],[d]]` and not `[['a'],['b'],[],['c'],[],[],['d']]` that yields `['a','b','c','d']`?

Comment: Thanks guys! Yes, sorry it's the latter, corrected now Hyperboreus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you starting with the strings `'a'`, `'b'`, etc.? If so then you can use `''.join` to convert `['a']` into `'a'` and `[]` into `''`.

```
[''.join(l) for l in list_of_lists]
```

Comment: Actually, for my purposes this is even better. @Rob has directly answered my question, but that method (my fault) is not good for the case when I have several strings in one list. Since each string will become a separate string entry, thus increasing the length. Thanks for the great answer!

Answer (score 5):

Simply choose `['']` instead of the empty list when presented with an empty sublist:

```
list_of_lists = [['a'],['b'], [], ['c'], [], [], ['d']]
[x for sublist in list_of_lists for x in sublist or ['']]
```

If you have some more complicated criteria for treating some sublists specially, you can use `... if ... else ...`:

```
[x for sublist in list_of_lists for x in (sublist if len(sublist)%2==1 else [42])]
```

P.s. I'm assumig that the lack of quotes in the original is an oversight.

Comment: That's brilliant thank you, and yes that was an oversight - corrected now

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
a = b = c = d = 3    
lol = [[a],[b],[],[c],[],[],[d]]

from itertools import chain
print list(chain.from_iterable(el or [[]] for el in lol))
# [3, 3, [], 3, [], [], 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> result = []
>>> for l in list_of_lists:
    if len(l) >0:
        result += l
    else:
        result.append('')


>>> result
['a', 'b', '', 'c', '', '', 'd']
```